# Updating fragment identifier in Shiny from session$clientData

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using an HTML template for a Shiny application and am trying to replicate dashboards' `tabPanel` functionality based on the URI's fragment identifier.

Specifically, given a number of nav links that act as page anchors, I want Shiny to take that fragment identifier, update any server-side objects as needed, and return the output that corresponds to whatever pseudo-tab the user clicked on. This is based on Joe Cheng's [college scorecard application](https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jcheng/scorecard-app/) (just swap out the query string for the page anchor). I'd also rather not go that route with a query string because the app sources a larger dataset with a large number of user-defined selections that would have to be encoded in the URI. Since each new search triggers a hard page refresh, that would probably be a not great user experience having the data reload, preprocess, etc. every time you made a minor change to your inputs.

The issue I'm running into is that Shiny stores only the *initial* URI hash in `session$clientData` and there's no way I've found to force that to update (with `invalidateLater`, `eventReactive`, or `observeEvent`) as the user navigates from `#summary` to `#bleep` to `#blorp`. Has anyone run into a similar problem before? Or is it possible refresh the `session$clientData` object without a hard page refresh?

The other option is to just add a new class to the CSS with `display: none;` for hidden divs and write a little bit of JS to handle things. Ideally, though, I'd prefer to find a Shiny-based solution.

My code looks similar to:

**index.html:**

```
...
<header role="banner">
  <h3 class="usa-display">My header!</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav active" href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="#blorp">Another Tab</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div data-display-if="output.appMode === 'summary' ">
  {{ renderVerbatimText("clientInfo") }}
</div>

<div data-display-if="output.appMode === 'blorp' ">
  <img src="assets/img/failWhale.jpg" />
</div>
...
```

**ui.R:**

```
function(req) {
  htmlTemplate(
    "www/index.html"
  )
}
```

**server.R:**

```
parseHashString <- function (str, nested = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(str) || nchar(str) == 0) {
    values <- "summary"
    return(values)
  }

  if (substr(str, 1, 1) == "#") {
    str <- substr(str, 2, nchar(str))
  }

  values <- strsplit(str, "#", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  values <- values[!is.na(values)]

  values <- values[values %in% c("summary", "blorp")]

  return(values[1])
}

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$appMode <- reactive({
    parseHashString(session$clientData$url_hash_initial)
  })

  outputOptions(output, "appMode", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)


  output$clientInfo<- renderText({
    cdata <- session$clientData
    cnames <- names(cdata)

    allvalues <- lapply(cnames, function(name) {
      paste(name, cdata[[name]], sep=" = ")
    })
    paste(allvalues, collapse = "\n")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out by just creating a custom Shiny input. Basically I just created an empty/hidden div to reflect the new Shiny input. On top of that is just a pretty standard input binding per [Rstudio's instructions](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-inputs). The only modifications I had to make were to trigger a callback any time the URI hash changed (in this case, after a user clicks any of the nav links). The nav click triggers `on("hashchange" function() {...})` which then forces `input$appHash` to update. Whatever the new URI hash is will be respected by any logic that I have in `server.R` and output can be conditionally displayed.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {{ headContent() }}
    {{ bootstrapLib() }}

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var hashBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
        $.extend(hashBinding, {
          find: function(scope) {
            return $(scope).find(".appHash");
          },
          getValue: function(el) {
            return $(el).val();
          },
          setValue: function(el, value) {
            $(el).val(value);
          },
          subscribe: function(el, callback) {
            $(el).on("change.hashBinding", function(e) {
              $(el).val(window.location.hash);
              callback();
            });
          },
          unsubscribe: function(el) {
            $(el).off(".hashBinding");
          }
        });

        Shiny.inputBindings.register(hashBinding);

        $('.nav').click(function () {
          $('.nav').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
          var el = $(".appHash");
          el.trigger("change");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header role="banner">
      <div class="appHash" id="appHash" style="display:none;"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav active" href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#bleep">Tab X</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#blorp">Tab Y</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#faq">F.A.Q.</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```